# Checking post content for a shortcode, but content is being returned as empty

Tags: shortcode, the-content, post-content

Alright so I am trying to check for a shortcode in the post content so that I can enqueue scripts as necessary.

I have this:

```
    if( plugin_has_shortcode() ) {
        // Load CSS
        wp_enqueue_style( 'plugin-css', 'plugin.css', array(), null );
    }
```

And here is my `plugin_has_shortcode` function:

```
    function plugin_has_shortcode() {
        global $post;

        if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '[shortcode' ) ) {
            return true;
        }

         return false;
    }
```

This works most of the time. The issue I am having is that when I add the shortcode to the top of the editor `[shortcode]` and no other content before it then `$post->post_content` comes back as an empty string and makes my check return false.

The other weird thing is that if I add any content above the shortcode - even just adding a `&nbsp;` above it - will make it work as intended.

Has anyone else encountered this? Is it a bug? Is there a way to fix it?

Any and all input much appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the shortcode is at the very beginning `strpos` returns 0 which is evaluated as false:

> Warning
>
> This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a
>   non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on
>   Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the
>   return value of this function.
>
> http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strpos.php

So change your code like this:

```
function plugin_has_shortcode() {
    global $post;
    if ( strpos( $post->post_content, '[shortcode' ) !== false ) {
        return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Or even shorter:

```
function plugin_has_shortcode() {
    global $post;
    return strpos( $post->post_content, '[shortcode' ) !== false;
}
```